# Engine/Clutch/Powertrain

Tags: engine, clutch, jeep, power-loss

When my engine is in neutral it reaches red line with no problem. It also has power in first and second gear. The problem happens when i am driving up a long incline, I will be in third or fourth gear flooring the gas but my rpm's wont go up and neither will my speed. What might be causing this and what parts would I have to change to fix this problem? I drive a 2020 Jeep JLU manual 6 Speed.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What grade of incline are you trying to climb? What exactly are you doing with your Rubi? If your engine/vehicle isn't gaining speed while doing this, sounds like your clutch is working fine.

Comment: So the inclines are small I live in Texas. They are very mild inclines on the freeway, and even on flat roads I will shift into 4/5/6 and I will maintain speed at 70mph, at about 2500 rpm. Then about 30 seconds later I start losing speed so I mash the gas pedal in order to try speed back up but nothing happens, speed keeps decreasing and rpms stay consistent or even drop a little bit. So I always would have to downshift to 3rd and even 3rd seems to be eiffy sometimes.

Comment: Seeing as how it's a 2020, it *has* got to be under warranty. Have you considered taking it in to see if there's an issue with it you might not be aware of? This isn't typical behavior for a vehicle which is running correctly.

Comment: It might still be, I bought it in 2019 and it has 30k on the odometer now. There's been no warning lights or codes thrown. Another thing that happens is my current MPG will severely drop from 20-22 to 10-12. I kind have little backfires too I think which makes me think it's getting the fuel but its not all igniting maybe? At least not all at the correct time but I don't know how to test that.

Comment: Basic warranty is 3yr/36k miles, with powertrain being 5yr/100k miles. Either way, it should be covered.